# Span with background in text only

Tags: html, css

I can't make my background only in my text. Always go further until the end of the screen.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```html
<div class="textSlide">
   <span id="firstTitle">We help you find everyone you</span>
   <span id="secondTitle">need to get you started.</span>
   <span id="thirdTitle">Look Ouch is an online meeting point where all kinds</span>
   <span id="fourthTitle">of artists can unite to make ideas happen.</span>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
.textSlide span { 
  z-index: 999; 
  position: relative; 
  margin-left: 10%; 
  font-family: Montserrat; 
  display: block; 
  padding: 5px; 
}
.textSlide #firstTitle { 
  margin-top: 120px; 
  font-size: 34px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  background-color: #7d37e6; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #secondTitle { 
  font-size: 34px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #7d37e6; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #thirdTitle { 
  font-size: 18px; 
  margin-top: 12px; 
  background-color: #7933e1; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #fourthTitle { 
  font-size: 18px; 
  margin-top: 5px; 
  background-color: #7933e1; 
  color: #fff; 
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w456u/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `display: block`, to `display: inline-block;`

http://jsfiddle.net/w456u/1/

Answer (score 2):

```css
.textSlide span { 
  z-index: 999; 
  position: relative; 
  margin-left: 10%; 
  font-family: Montserrat; 
  display: inline-block; 
  padding: 5px; 
}
.textSlide #firstTitle { 
  margin-top: 120px; 
  font-size: 34px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  background-color: #7d37e6; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #secondTitle { 
  font-size: 34px; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  margin-top: 5px; 
  background-color: #7d37e6; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #thirdTitle { 
  font-size: 18px; 
  margin-top: 12px; 
  background-color: #7933e1; 
  color: #fff; 
}
.textSlide #fourthTitle { 
  font-size: 18px; 
  margin-top: 5px; 
  background-color: #7933e1; 
  color: #fff; 
}
```